# Extract specific pattern from string in MySQL:

Tags: mysql

I would like to extract specific pattern from string in MySQL.

The column contains specific string like xxx-atg168d and xxx-atg444-6x. From these string, I want to extract atg168 and atg444 only. How can I perform this in MySQL?

```
**Input_column**  
xxx-atg168d  
xxx-atg444-6x  
xxx-atg1689d   
xxx-atg16507d  
xxx-atg444d-6x 
xxx-atg444c-6x  

**Output_column**  
atg168  
atg444  
atg1689  
atg16507  
atg444
atg444
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may meet your specification:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR( t.col ,INSTR( t.col ,'-')+1),'-',1)
```

This assumes that you want to return the portion of the string following the first dash character, up to the next dash character (if present). If no dash characters exist within the string, the entire string will be returned.

**EDIT**

Ooops. That expression also includes the trailing "d". If it's just a trailing "d" character that needs to be removed...

```
TRIM(TRAILING 'd' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR( t.col ,INSTR( t.col ,'-')+1),'-',1))
```

In the more general case, to remove any "non-digit" character from the end (not just a "d"), things get pretty ugly. We need to check the rightmost character, and see if it matches a character we wnt to keep. If it's not, we shorten the string by one character.

```
IF( INSTR('0123456789',RIGHT(
       @t := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR( t.col ,INSTR( t.col ,'-')+1),'-',1)
    ,1))
, @t
, SUBSTRING( @t, 1, CHAR_LENGTH( @t )-1)
)
```

I made use of a user-defined variable here to avoid repeating the same expression multiple times. It's not required that we do that.  The `@t :=`assignment can be removed, and other occurrences of `@t` can be replaced with the expression that was assigned to `@t`.

The literal `'0123456789'` in that expression is the set of characters that we don't want to remove from the end of the string.

Comment: Hi, i tried this method. But i have one record like xxx-atg444d-6x. For this string, it is returning atg444d. Plz suggest me to solve this.

Comment: @PyPerl: I noticed the trailing 'd' character after I posted my answer; I've updated my answer to add a TRIM() function to remove trailing "d" characters.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Like d, i have also other trailing character. How can i generalize your solution for any character?

Comment: Thanks spencer for your help. I edited your code to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTRING function , like this :

```
select SUBSTRING(column_name ,5,6) from table_name;
```

Here 5 is starting position and 6 is length of sub-string getting extracted from string.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The length of target string is not constant. There are also record like xxx-atg1689d and xxx-atg16870d

Answer (score 0):

Thanks spencer for your suggestions. I edited your code to get the solution for my query. Here is the update query,

```
left(substring_index (substr(subid,instr(subid,'-')+1),'-',1) , char_length(substring_index (substr(subid,instr(subid,'-')+1),'-',1))-1)
```